# How can i superscript a character in R?

Tags: r, superscript

Is there a way to add superscript to a character string in R? For example can the '2' here be superscript:

```
"cm2"
```

Comment: Hi Steve do you need a string or a plot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using unicode, you can check it with the `[link][1]`

```
cat("\U0063\U006D\U00B2")
cm²
```